# I can't find reaction enthalpy ∆H for water formation reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, enthalpy

$$\ce{1/2 O2(g) + H2(g) → H2O (l)}$$

The tabulated value is $\Delta H = \pu{−285.8 kJ/mol}$

I'm using the bond energies values for each molecule and for some reason, I am getting a different result, not even close to $\pu{-285 kJ/mol}$.

Bond dissociation energies:

$\ce{H-H} = \pu{436 kJ/mol}$

$\ce{O=O} = \pu{499 kJ/mol}$

$\ce{O-H} = \pu{464 kJ/mol}$

My attempt to calculate from bond dissociation energies:

(500.1/2) + 436 → 464.2

250 + 436 → 928

($∆H$ found is positive)

Comment: Well, i wanted to see someone doing the correct way, so i could see my mistakes and fix them

Comment: Bond formation is exothermic and bond breaking is endothermic.

Comment: i know that, i want to know how to get the result using the bond energies.

Comment: @BrunoMachado Thanks for showing your attempt. Zhe guessed correctly that you had trouble with plus and minus. I guessed incorrectly that you where concerned about the difference between -285 and -245 kJ/mol. Now we know.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the tally of bonds:

1. One $\ce{H-H}$ bond broken
2. One half $\ce{O=O}$ double bond broken
3. Two $\ce{O-H}$ bonds made

Breaking bonds costs (positive sign), making bonds gains (negative sign). The result will be an estimate of turning reactants to products in the gas phase. It is an estimate because the strength of an $\ce{O-H}$ bond depends on what else is attached to the oxygen. For H-H and O=O, this is no problem because there is only one molecule, respectively, with that kind of bond.

$$\Delta H = \pu{436 kJ/mol} + \pu{249.5 kJ/mol} - \pu{928 kJ/mol} =  \pu{-242.5 kJ/mol}$$

We got the right sign and are not too far off in magnitude.

**Why is the physical state important?**

In solids and liquids, there are intermolecular interactions that contribute to the enthalpy. This is why the enthalpy of sublimation and boiling is positive - it takes energy to break the intermolecular forces. Here are the values for enthalpy of formation for water in the two states at room temperature:

$$\Delta H_\mathrm{f}(\ce{H2O(l)}) = \pu{-285.8 kJ/mol}$$

$$\Delta H_\mathrm{f}(\ce{H2O(g)}) = \pu{-241.8 kJ/mol}$$

And here is the enthalpy of vaporization

$$\Delta H_\mathrm{vap}(\ce{H2O(g)}) = \pu{43.99 kJ/mol}$$

Comment: But ∆H is products - reagents, right?

Comment: why you did reagents - products?

Comment: Products - reactants is for calculating reaction enthalpies from $\Delta H_f$ values. Bonds broken - bonds made (i.e. bonds dissociation energies for the reactants - bond dissociation energies for the products) is what you need for this kind of exercise.

Comment: It is a common confusion. First, sort out what type of problem it is, then make sure the pluses and minuses are correct.

Comment: but i still can't understand how water has more energy than the sum of reactants, considering that this is an exorthermic reaction

Comment: Let's consider a simpler reaction: two hydrogen atoms forming the dihydrogen molecule. This is an exothermic reaction. the dihydrogen molecule has less energy that the two separate atoms (it just gave away that energy in an exothermic reaction). It would take energy (endothermic reaction) to separate the molecule into atoms again. In general, molecules with stronger bonds have the lower energy, molecules with weak bonds have higher energy.

Comment: hypotetically speaking, what would be the values for h and h2, just to exemplificate?

Comment: $\Delta H_f$ for H2 is zero by definition. $\Delta H_f$ for the H-atom would be positive, 218 kJ/mol. If you do products - reactants for the enthalpies of formation, you get a negative value - the expected exothermic reaction. Or you could simply say you are making an H-H bond and not breaking anything. With the bond dissociation energy of +436 kJ/mol, you would come to the same conclusion (bond formation: exothermic: negative change in enthalpy).

Comment: Here is the logic for the formulas: In one case (using enthalpy of formation) we go from reactants via elements to products. Enthalpy of formation is elements to compounds, so reactants to elements is the wrong direction - change of sign. In the other case (bond dissociation energies) we go from reactants to atoms (or fragments) to products. We are making, not dissociating bonds of the product, so products to atoms is the wrong direction - change of sign.

Comment: @KarstenTheis Sorry, I don't think I made it clear that that comment was to Bruno... :( Probably best for me just to delete it at this point...

Comment: @Zhe no problem, I thought I should spell out the rationale. I could have put it in the answer, but I didn’t know what the misconception was when I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

Karsten Theis' answer is a perfect one for your question. He also did his best to explain why is he used the bond-making bond-breaking sign conversion but you are still in mind set of product-reactant explanation. So I decided to explain it in different direction.

Remember the law of conservation of energy, which states that the total energy of an isolated system remains constant? So it applies here as well. As Karsten Theis has explained, for the reaction, $\ce{H2 (g) + 1/2 O2 (g) -> H2O (g)}$:

$$\text{energies of $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{1/2 O2}$ } = \text{energy of $\ce{H2O}$ + energy absorbed or released} $$

Thus, $$\pu{436 kJ/mol} + \pu{\frac{499}{2} kJ/mol} = \pu{928 kJ/mol} + \Delta H $$ 
$$\therefore \;  \Delta H = \pu{436 kJ/mol} + \pu{\frac{499}{2} kJ/mol} - \pu{928 kJ/mol} = \pu{−242.5 kJ/mol}$$

Rest of the explanation to get $\Delta H_f (\ce{H2O(l)})$ is exactly same as Karsten Theis'. I hope it is clear to you now.